# Query help. Remove rows where duration equals zero

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [list of results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fhYVYvK0EBK1S6VYbpzYhOGNKIHKFw8UP7_jRZg3hgY/edit#gid=523946874) which include a column with duration time. I want to exclude any rows where the duration is zero. I tried the following without success.

`not M contains '00:00:00.000'`

`M > 0`

`not M contains '12:00:00 AM'`

I suspect it has something to do with the way the duration is formatted in the `uploadData!A:M` sheet. Here's the formula in question and the [spreadsheet in question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fhYVYvK0EBK1S6VYbpzYhOGNKIHKFw8UP7_jRZg3hgY/edit#gid=523946874).

`=query(uploadData!A:M,"Select B, C, H, I, M where not(C) contains '"&JOIN("|",filter!A:A)&"' and  B contains 'Incoming' and not B is null and not H is null ",1)`

Comment: I update the data frequently and would prefer not to have to do any manually deleting. I did figure out how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I just used a FILTER function to remove the zero durations before wrapping it with a query. You'll notice I had to change the column references from letters to numbers to get it to work correctly.

`=query(FILTER(uploadData!A:M,uploadData!M:M>0),"Select Col2, Col3, Col8, Col9, Col13 where not Col3 contains '"&JOIN("' and not Col3 contains '",filter(filter!A2:A,filter!A2:A<>""))&"' and  Col2 contains 'Incoming' and not Col2 is null and not Col9 is null Order by Col13",1)`